# Extract specific particle id variable from a netCDF file

Tags: netcdf, cdo-climate, nco

I have a netCDF file output from a particle dispersion model (GNOME).
As it is a particle dispersion model, I have every particle identified by a particle id variable:

int id(data) ;

```
            id:description = "particle ID" ;

            id:units = "1" ;
```

I need to extract only some specific particle id and their locations. I have tried with cdo and nco operators and I get these errors:

- ncks -v longitude,latitude -d id,62001. infile.nc outputfile.nc
  **ncks: ERROR dimension id is not in input file**
- cdo -select,name=latitude,longitude,id=62968  infile.nc outputfile.nc
  **cdo    select (Abort): Unsupported selection keyword: 'id'!**

I hope someone could help me. Thanks

Comment: iis "id" a variable as you state in the question, or a dimension?  your nco command tries to extract a dimension but the error indicates it is a variable, perhaps it would help to post the entire output from ncdump -h to the question so we can see the whole netcdf file structure

Answer (score 1):

The dimension is actually named "data". I suggest you rename the dimension to "id". Then your command should work:

```
ncrename -d data,id in.nc
ncks -v longitude,latitude -d id,62001. in.nc out.nc
```

or you could leave the names alone, and if the id is really the data index, then this should work:

```
   ncks -v longitude,latitude -d data,62001 in.nc out.nc
```

NB: no decimal point this time since data is not a coordinate, as explained [here](http://nco.sf.net/nco.html#hyp).

EDIT: 20210921 in response to comment below, unless I am missing something, the dataset would need to have a variable `traj` dimensioned `traj(time,data)` in order for the suggested commands to have the result you desire. The header of your file shows no such variable.

Comment: Thank you, both commands work but only for one time-step and not for all the time-steps available in the file.